# Problem concerning Numerical Solutions of Nonlinear Systems of Equations (Burden and Faires)

Tags: numerical-methods, maple

I need help with this particular question:

The nonlinear system

1. $3x_1 - \cos (x_2 x_3) - \frac{1}{2} = 0$
2. $x{_1}^2 - 625x{_2}^2 - \frac{1}{4}=0$
3. $\exp ^{-x_1x_2} + 20x_3 + \frac{10\Pi -3}{3}=0$

has a singular Jacobian matrix at the solution. Apply Newton's method with **x**$^{(0)} = (1,1,-1)^t$. Note that convergence may be slow or may not occur within a reasonable number of iterations.

My attempt on Maple:[image][image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Solving it by-hand is a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `NewtonMV` procedure, try changing,

```
 A := subs(s,f);
```

to,

```
 A := eval(J, [s]);
```

or to,

```
 A := subs(s, J);
```

Also, change the call `LinearSolve(...)` to `:-LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve(...)` so that it gets the right export from the right top package, regardless of whether you've loaded any subpackage of `Student`.

Personally, I'd rather see `evalf` wrapped around each of the two arguments to `LinearSolve` than around its call, if only so that the very first iteration doesn't attempt an exact subcomputation.

So, something like,

```
 dx := :-LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve( evalf(A), evalf(-fx) );
```

Please note that you can inline code into your Questions and Answers here see the menubar above the editing region. It's not so helpful to paste images of code.

[edited, after all the typos have been resolved]
You might want to consider additional stopping criteria. Apart from a maximal number of iterations to allow, you could stop when either the increment `dx` got small enough, or when the evaluation of `f` got close enough to zero (ie. x is considered a root).

```
restart:

NewtonMV:=proc(f,v,x0,n,xtol,ftol)
local i,result,J,x,fx,A,dx,s;
J:=VectorCalculus:-Jacobian(f,v);
x:=x0;
dx:=Vector([infinity,infinity,infinity]);
fx:=Vector([infinity,infinity,infinity]);
result:=convert(x0,list);
for i from 1 to n
  while :-LinearAlgebra:-Norm(dx)>xtol
    and :-LinearAlgebra:-Norm(fx)>ftol do
   s:=[seq(v[i]=x[i],i=1..nops(v))];
   fx:=evalf(eval(f,s));
   A:=evalf(eval(J,s));
   dx:=:-LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve(evalf(A),evalf(-fx));
   if indets(dx,name)<>{} then
      dx:=subs([seq(p=0,p=indets(dx,name))],dx);
   end if;
   x:=x+dx;
   result:=result,convert(x,list);
end do;
printf("\nnumber of iterations: %a\n\n",i-1);
printf("final increment dx, and its norm:\n      %a ,  %a\n\n",
       convert(dx,list), :-LinearAlgebra:-Norm(dx));
printf("substitution of solution x into f, and its norm:\n      %a ,  %a\n\n",
       convert(eval(f,s),list), :-LinearAlgebra:-Norm(fx));
return [result];
end proc:

lhs1:=3*x1-cos(x2*x3)-1/2;
lhs2:=x1^2-625*x2^2-1/4;
lhs3:=exp(-x1*x2)+20*x3+(10*Pi-3)/3;

NewtonMV(Vector([lhs1,lhs2,lhs3]),[x1,x2,x3],
         Vector([1,1,-1]), 400, 1e-5, 1e-7);
```

That is not intended to be the epitome of great coding, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: I've done all that bu I'm getting this error now: > r5 := NewtonMV(Vector([lhs1, lhs2, lhs3]), [x1, x2, x3], Vector([0, 0, 0]), 10); 

Error, (in LinearAlgebra:-LinearSolve) inconsistent system

Comment: Try a different initial Vector than `Vector([0,0,0])`. Your original posted Question mentions using `Vector([1,1,-1])` as the initial point.

Comment: I've used the $Vector(1,1,-1)$, but now Maple is still evaluating for 10 mins.

Comment: Why is there an instance of `x^2` in `lhs2`? Shouldn't it be `x2^2`?

Comment: Also, in `lhs3` the first term should be `exp(x1*x2)` and not `exp(-x1*x2)` as you have it. And the last term in `lhs2` should be `1/4` and not `-1/4` as you have it, yes?

Comment: I have fixed the typos and everything else is fine. In lhs3 the first term is indeed exp(-x1*x2).